# Replace text to make markdown or formatting

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace `*hello*` to *hello* how will i be able to do that? and the same but with other prefixes

```
let content = '*Hello*, my **friend** how are you?'

      function formatString(content) {
        let step1 = content.split(" ").join(" ").replaceAll("\n\n", "</br></br>");
        //replace
      }
      formatString(content)//should return '<i>Hello</i>, my <b>friend</b> how are you?'
```

I tried using regex but I was only able to replace `*string*` to *string only instead of string*

Comment: Use a Markdown to HTML converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the replaceAll method with the regex /*(.*?)*/g to replace all occurrences of *string* with *string*, and /**(.*?)**/g to replace all occurrences of **string** with **string**. The g flag makes sure that all occurrences are replaced, not just the first one.

```js
let content = '*Hello*, my **friend** how are you?'

function formatString(content) {
  let step1 = content.split(" ").join(" ").replaceAll("\n\n", "</br></br>");
  let step2 = step1.replaceAll(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<i>$1</i>");
  let step3 = step2.replaceAll(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
  return step3;
}

console.log(formatString(content))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [ShowdownJS library](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) to handle Markdown to HTML conversion.

```js
let content = '*Hello*, my **friend** how are you?';
const converter = new showdown.Converter();
let res = converter.makeHtml(content);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/showdown/dist/showdown.min.js"></script>
```